# copy the last column in the first position awk

Tags: bash, text, sed, awk, preg-replace

I want to copy the first value of colum in the first position and comment out the old value. 
For example :

```
word1 word2 1233425     -----> 1233425 word1 word2 #1233425
word1 word2 word3 49586 -----> 49586   word1 word2 word3   #49586
```

I don't know the number of words preceding the number.

I tried with an awk script :

```
awk '{$1="";score=$NF;$NF="";print $score $0 #$score}' file
```

But It does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this? It is pretty similar to yours.

```
$ awk '{score=$NF; $NF="#"$NF; print score, $0}' file
1233425 word1 word2 #1233425
49586 word1 word2 word3 #49586
```

Note that in your case you are emptying `$1`, which is not necessary. Just store `score` as you did and then add `#` to the beginning of `$NF`.

Comment: I don't understand why score is overwritten when I use this code

Comment: What do you mean, @GiuseppePes? Isn't it outputting the desired values?

Comment: The script is correct. but when I use in my files I get this output :`  word1 word2 #1233425`. It starts with a space.

Comment: That is strange, @GiuseppePes, as there is no written spaces. Are you using exactly this code? Also, you could update your question with the exact input file you are using.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The files I am using have been created in windows where the new line is encoded as "\r\n". The script does not take into account "\r".

Comment: your logo picture told me that, you from an old man grown up to a young man. :D  ! +1

Comment: Ok then firstly you should "unix-ize" them with the `dos2unix` command, @GiuseppePes

Comment: @Kent haha I am a kind of Benjamin Button :D

Comment: @fedorqui we'll see when would you get a baby pic... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{f=$NF;$NF="#" $NF;print f,$0}' file
```

---

Since we posted the same answer, here is a shorter variation :)

```
awk '{$0=$NF FS$0;$NF="#"$NF}1' file
```

`$0=$NF FS$0` add last field to line
`$NF="#"$NF` add `#` to last field.
`1` print line

Comment: Exactly 13 seconds, just hover in the "answered X mins ago" : )

Answer (score 1):

A perl way to do it:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.+ )(\d+)/$2 $1 #$2/' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)/\2 \1 #\2/' YourFile
```

with GNU sed add -posix option